# why am i able to modify private members in a public method of other class, when returned from a public method of same class

Tags: c#, access-modifiers, private-members, c#-7.0

I am able to update private members of a class instance from main method of other class. why was I allowed to do that. Is it like, its the use of "ref" keyword?

I tried modifying using "ref" keyword.

```
using System;

namespace Test2
{
    class A
    {
        private int a=10; 
        public ref int M() 
        {
            return ref a;
        }
        virtual public void display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("class A");
        }
    }
    class B:A
    { 

    }
    class Program
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            B b = new B();
            ref int a = ref b.M();
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            a = 20;
            Console.WriteLine(b.M());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your public function returns a reference to that private member, making it not so private anymore.

Answer (score 9):

When you return a ref, that means "the caller gets to make an alias for the variable I have returned."

If that variable is private, that doesn't matter. The caller gets to make an alias for that variable; if you didn't want the caller to do that, you should not have given them that ability!

Remember, privacy is **only about names**.  `a` is private, so **the name `a` may only be used from within that class**.  That is all that private means. It does not mean that the variable may not be changed; it means that the variable cannot be identified by that name outside of the class.

In your example, you are not identifying the variable being modified by its name *in the class*. You're identifying it by its alias, which is the *local* variable `a`.

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns

`A.M()` returns a reference for `A.a` and you assign that reference to the variable `a`, which is not the value of `A.a` but a reference to `A.a`.

So, assigning a value to `a` is assigning a value to `A.a`.

Answer (score -3):

C# has types by reference and types by value

Types values are primitive tipes like int, float, double and when you pass it to a method you really pass the value, so is like pass a copy of the object.
The keyword ref modifies this behavior and pass the reference to the object, the memory address of a value not value, so when you modified the value affects all the classes that have a reference to it, the value is the same in all

Please take a look:

[ref keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref)